# SharePoint Custom List Form performance issue after submitting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

I have custom new and edit forms for adding/editing items in sharepoint 2013.When I am editing any field,it saves normally.When I add any new item in list and click on submit,it takes 5mins to redirect it to AllItems View but internally items gets added immediately.

How can I debug where it is taking time in newform.aspx after click on submit?What could be probable reasons?

When I see network tab, there is only one call which takes 5.6mins when I click on submit on add new item form.It is not infopath form and list has total 500 items.it contains 6-7 lookup columns but edit form is working fine.I have commneted all my custom JS but still it takes same time.

Comment: Is this form customized with InfoPath?

Comment: Or maybe some custom JavaScript code validating and/or making calls?

Comment: no it is not infopath and same issue while i commnet my custom code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following cmdlets to enable Developer Dashboard to track which request may cost a long time to load.

```
$content = ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService)
$appsetting = $content.DeveloperDashboardSettings
$appsetting.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::On
$appsetting.Update()
```

In addtion, if the list is large, it may have performance issue.

There are some blogs about troubleshooting Performance issue for your reference:
[Tips on troubleshooting SharePoint 2013 performance issues](https://www.abelsolutions.com/tips-on-troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-performance-issues/)
[SharePoint Performance Issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ahmedamin/2017/11/17/sharepoint-performance-issue/)